# Fastest way to calculate absolute values of a list

Tags: python, list, absolute-value

I have a question about calculating the absolute value of a list. I have written a short code to calculate the absolute value of each single element from a list and I was wondering if there is a faster way of doing this, Thanks!

```
test_list = [5, -60, 74, -83, -120]
result =  [abs(i) for i in test_list]
print(result)
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: If you need faster and are working with lots of data, maybe Numpy is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/) package is a package for doing fast maths operations in Python. It is so fast because it itself is not actually written in Python (which is a very slow language), but instead in C (which is very fast), and it is very optimised.

After installing numpy:

```
pip install numpy
```

This code can be rewritten as:

```py
import numpy as np

test_list = np.array([5, -60, 74, -83, -120])
result = np.abs(test_list)
print(result)
```

It will work much faster this way with larger arrays, although bear in mind that for small arrays (like this example), it is not worth it as `numpy` takes a while to import.

Comment: @Mark True, I will edit my question to specify that this is only true for larger arrays, but this is probably what the OP meant anyway.